PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = '/Users/myusername/firebase.json'
I am setting up my Flutter project with Firebase. I have setup it using flutterfire configure and I can see the firebase.json was created inside my app's root directory.
I can launch my Android app with no issue and I can see my Crashlytics reports coming in for Android. The problem is with iOS app, when I want to launch the app, I am getting below error:
Unhandled exception:
PathNotFoundException: Cannot open file, path = '/Users/myusername/firebase.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
#0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:55:9)
#1      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:381:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _File.readAsBytes.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:562:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _File.readAsString (dart:io/file_impl.dart:621:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      appleConfigFromFirebaseJson (package:flutterfire_cli/src/common/utils.dart:286:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      UploadCrashlyticsSymbols._getConfigurationFromFirebaseJsonFile (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/upload_symbols.dart:278:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      UploadCrashlyticsSymbols.run (package:flutterfire_cli/src/commands/upload_symbols.dart:331:34)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:212:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      main (file:///Users/myusername/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterfire_cli-1.0.0/bin/flutterfire.dart:63:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Removed stale file '/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-egqrgdeioyfvqjgozczypudejvlm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-AA5FB794F195D0E14D219BF0.sh'

Any idea on why this is happening?

Hi @Mike, did you fixed that error?

After my colleague merged with my branch, suddenly it works now. Not too sure what happened... :/

I just fixed that error because my parent folder of project contain " " space character :))

Ahh, I think it's the same thing for me. I did this also at one point but not while troubleshooting for this issue. Put this as answer and I'll accept it.

As per @Nhật Trần comment, my issue is due to my directory folder containing space. After removing the space, then I no longer have this issue.
